# Pushing an element in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

so I am working with a multidimensional array.

For example, the output data I am trying to get is like this:

```
[[element 1],[element 2], [element 3]]
```

This is my PHP code (minus the entire prepared statement which goes above the bind ((not included as this is working fine)):

```
$insertquery->bind_result($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_fcm_old, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_hull_id_old, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_name_old, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_length_old, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_old, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_old, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_year_old, $vessel_value_new, $vessel_value_old, $owner_id_new, $owner_id_old, $loss_payee_id_new, $loss_payee_id_old, $policy_id_new, $policy_id_old, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_start_date_old, $policy_end_date_new, $policy_end_date_old, $vessel_fcm, $vessel_hull_id, $vessel_name, $vessel_manufacturer_id);
while ($insertquery->fetch()){
    if($vessel_fcm_new != $vessel_fcm_old){
        $data = array($vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_fcm_old);
    }
    if ($vessel_name_new != $vessel_name_old){
         array_push($data, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_name_old);
    }
    $data_return[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($data_return);
```

Basically, the code is initiated to iterate through each database row, and if the condition is met it will build an array, and add the array to the array object. So the outcome would look like this, if the matching conditions are met:

```
[[row 1], [row2], [row3]]
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\htdocs\alterajax.php on line 16
```

But I am specifying the array already, or at least I think I am (`$data`).
This is also what I see as the output:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,["FCMjgis","fFH465","Smokey","GIIGE"]]
```

I'm sure this is just something minor, but I would appreciate some guidance if you can assist. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do `vessel_fcm_new` and `vessel_fcm_old` exist for each one of the rows? You might want to expand your conditional to also check neither are null.

Comment: Looks like $data is not initialized properly, it is initialized conditionally so you must initialize the variable as an empty array before your first "if" statement.

Comment: @ObsidianAge This is a tracking table used to track different updates, so the idea here is to show the user only rows that have changes. For example if new = old, then don't show the row. So, yes they exist for each row.

Comment: @Geolim4 I tried to initialize it before, but that just adds empty parenthesis, still outputs the same as above, just without null.

Comment: In that case, just check that $data is effectively initialized using `isset` before using in `array_push`.

Comment: @Geolim4 Got it. I just needed to initialize. Thank you. And I was playing around with dummy data, not realizing some of it was repeating lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, just initialize your variable or test if its initialized using `isset`

```
$insertquery->bind_result($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_fcm_old, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_hull_id_old, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_name_old, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_length_old, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_old, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_old, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_year_old, $vessel_value_new, $vessel_value_old, $owner_id_new, $owner_id_old, $loss_payee_id_new, $loss_payee_id_old, $policy_id_new, $policy_id_old, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_start_date_old, $policy_end_date_new, $policy_end_date_old, $vessel_fcm, $vessel_hull_id, $vessel_name, $vessel_manufacturer_id);
while ($insertquery->fetch()){
    if($vessel_fcm_new != $vessel_fcm_old){
        $data = array($vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_fcm_old);
    }
    if (isset($data) && $vessel_name_new != $vessel_name_old){
         array_push($data, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_name_old);
         $data_return[] = $data;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data_return);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to initialize your variables!

In this case, all I needed to do was initialize the $data array. I did this by placing `$data = [];` (or also `$data = array();`) on the line above the while loop